# AngularJS ng-repeat Expression to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to read out data from my Database with AngularJS which is working fine, but I can't figure out, how to get Data out of ng-repeat to a JavaScript Object or something.

The data is now an expression, after the ng-repeat, right? I read something about a parser option but I couldnt understand how it works or even if this is what I needed.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">


<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in records">
    <td>{{ x.Timestamp }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.PT1 }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://localhost/tests/dataconn.php")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.records = response.data.records;});
});

</script>
```

So what I need: the x.Timestamp and the x.PT# passed to JavaScript. :)

Kind regards,

Max

Edit: SORRY, forgot to add my code!

Comment: show your code ...

Comment: 1) There is no code 2) AngularJs cannot read from database directly 3) You are totally unclear in what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the code. I already read out the data from the database as I said above, only thing I need is to get the data from the database now to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable out of angular context then store in it.

for Ex :

```
<script> 
    var testData={};  // Global object
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("http://localhost/tests/dataconn.php")
      .then(function (response) {
       $scope.records = response.data.records;
       testData.records = $scope.records; // you can access this **testData** globally.
      });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed.

Comment: THis works, but do you know how I can access this data now? When i try to print it with document.write.testData.records.PT1 it does not work, can you help me here too?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot directly call send to JavaScript, but you can do it on any action .
For example

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in items">
<td><a href="#" ng-click="yourfunction(x)">{{x}}</a></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I need to click it, it wont help me since i need it to be automatically when loading the page. :/